# jQuery new FormData() assign additional post data

Tags: jquery, form-data

How can I assign additional post variables in following example:

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
data.append('pic', $(".filename").files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: 'upload.php',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  dataType : 'json',
  data: data
});
```

I also want to send additional post data like `{action:"upload", event:"today"}`

Comment: `myFormData.append('action','upload')` and `myFormData.append('event','today')` and your `data` should have `myFormData`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Thank you.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)